# Home feed get specific links

Tags: facebook-graph-api, filter, stream, facebook-fql

So I want to get linked typed post from users home stream
But I want it to have specific url like "where link url = example.com"

As a result I will have a data of my friends who had shared that link.

First I tried querying the home with

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=example (worked but partly, only old posts)

Then I did:

```
friends_id = [Get all ids]
[foreach friends_id as id]

    make facebook api call to that id
    get all links that user had shared
    [foreach links as link]

        filter all of them for a specific link        
        [if shared the link] save user to an array
```

And that was really slow! 6 sec for a person

And lastly I tried to get it with 
fql using stream and stream filter. The problem with that I can get posts but I can't query what is that link

Printing the array gives me:

```
        [post_id] => **********
        [actor_id] => *******
        [target_id] => 
        [message] => 
        [action_links] => 
        [type] => 80
```

So how can I achieve my goal of having an array of data of my friends who had shared that link?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, only possible by using
friends_id = [Get all ids]
[foreach friends_id as id]

```
make facebook api call to that id
get all links that user had shared
[foreach links as link]

    filter all of them for a specific link        
    [if shared the link] save user to an array
```

Comment: I tried that method with both fql and graph api and fql seemed a bit faster but facebook response time is terrible. It took 3-6 sec for every user to get their links. and 5*350 means 30 minutes. 
Is there anything to make it faster?