# How to get graph facebook links that only contain youtube links

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I want to get only the **youtube.com** links in my or my friends wall.
I am using the following Facebook Graph API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/links&fields=link
```

And it's giving me nice list like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jozTK-MqEXQ", 
      "id": "311162005645378", 
      "created_time": "2012-06-21T08:35:46+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=385669064830879&set=a.384862068244912.91206.150665568331231&type=1", 
      "id": "136116106525926", 
      "created_time": "2012-06-14T10:12:33+0000"
    },
```

The list is long, so this is just a sample.

I want to be able to get only the links that are from **youtube.com**

I mean, as you see there are links like the second that it's from **facebook**, not youtube.com

I want to be able to get a list of all my or my friends **youtube.com** links.

**is this possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think the Facebook API offers a filtering function. So, you will need to get the entire list and iterate through it yourself in order to filter out the youtube.com links.

A simple approach would be to copy out all the links that begin with **http://www.youtube.com** into another list.

Also: Possible duplicate of [Home feed get specific links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693546/home-feed-get-specific-links)

Comment: ATM i have a working code that pull out all the youtube links as you said. take all the data and run a Startwith(h**p://youtube......etc

But, it's takes 3-6 sec to be able to display a one friend videos...

Do you or any one have an idea what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Well, that is because the list is large. Perhaps you could divide up the work and create a multi threaded solution.

Comment: I'm trying to get the max preformance... is there a RIGHT way to do this? a URL will be great! thanks!

Comment: Max performance is a separate issue to this question. You need to research processing large lists. Multi threaded is a solution in my opinion.